# Is there a minimum character limit for TextWriter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io

Is there a minimum content limit to use TextWriter for writing to stream

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();    
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(ms);
```

Below code does not write data to stream. And stream is empty

```
for (int ix = 0; ix < 10; ix++)
{
textWriter.WriteLine(ix.ToString());
}
```

Below code writes the data to stream

```
for (int ix = 0; ix < 1000; ix++)
{
textWriter.WriteLine(ix.ToString());
}
```

I have searched msdn and did not find any thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to flush the stream before the writes take effect.  This can be accomplished by calling Flush() directly, or by closing the stream.

Comment: Thanks Eric. It worked with Flush(). I am still confused why it would not write when loop is iterated 10 times and successfully write when the loop is iterated 1000 times

Comment: @Kishore - because there is a buffer that holds on to the data until the buffer gets full, or you call flush.  If you write 1000 times, the buffer fills up and writes.  Imagine you have drops of water.  Would you rather take each drop and carry it across the room?  Or would you rather put down a bucket and wait for the bucket to fill up, then carry it across the room?